# Use aligned math environment within subcaptionbox

Tags: subcaption

I am trying to put an image next to an equation and aligning the subcaptions using `subcaptionbox`. Unfortunately I am having some issues. See the following MWE:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \subcaptionbox{Plot of example character.\label{fig:original_plot}}{\input{Figures/plot.tex}}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \subcaptionbox{Format of original data.\label{fig:original_format}}{%
                $$
                \begin{aligned}
                    X   &=  \{\underbrace{\left[\left(x_{1,1},y_{1,1}\right),\dotsc,\left(x_{1,n_1},y_{1,n_1}\right)\right]}_{\text{stroke 1}}, \\
                        &\qquad     \underbrace{\left[\left(x_{2,1},y_{2,1}\right),\dotsc,\left(x_{2,n_2},y_{2,n_2}\right)\right]}_{\text{stroke 2}},   \\
                        &\qquad     \underbrace{\left[\left(x_{3,1},y_{3,1}\right),\dotsc,\left(x_{3,n_3},y_{3,n_3}\right)\right]}_{\text{stroke 3}}\}
                \end{aligned}
                $$%
            }
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{.....}
    \label{fig:original}
\end{figure}
```

When compiling, I receive the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33 ^^I^^I^^I}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use single `$` signs, in this case; *never* use `$$` in LaTeX. But what's the purpose of nesting `\subcaptionbox` in `subfigure`?

Comment: ...see [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 1):

A `\subcaptionbox` is essentially a horizontal box, so `$$` means just an empty formula.

On the other hand, `$$` should never be used in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Here's an implementation of your idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp] %%% <---- NOT just h

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption{Plot of example character.\label{fig:original_plot}}
\end{subfigure}% <--- Important!
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{align*}
X = \{ & {\underbrace{[(x_{1,1},y_{1,1}),\dots,(x_{1,n_1},y_{1,n_1})]}_{\text{stroke 1}}}, \\
       & {\underbrace{[(x_{2,1},y_{2,1}),\dots,(x_{2,n_2},y_{2,n_2})]}_{\text{stroke 2}}}, \\
       & {\underbrace{[(x_{3,1},y_{3,1}),\dots,(x_{3,n_3},y_{3,n_3})]}_{\text{stroke 3}}} \}
\end{align*}

\caption{Format of original data.\label{fig:original_format}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Global caption\label{fig:original}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the removal of all `\left` and `\right`, the different alignment point and the braces around `\underbrace`.

[image]